# $a_1,a_2,...,a_6,b_1,...,b_6 $then show that $-1<a_1.b_1+...+a_6.b_6<1$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$$a_1,a_2,...,a_6,b_1,...,b_6 \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$a_1^2+...+a_6^2=b_1^2+...+b_6^2=1$$ then show that $-1\leq a_1.b_1+...+a_6.b_6\leq 1$
I have showed for $i\in[1,6];$ $-1\leq a_i\leq1$ and $-1\leq b_i\leq 1$ how can I continue

Comment: Looks like standard Cauchy-Schwartz to me. By the way shouldn't the inequalities be not strict?

Comment: We can avoid using Cauchy-Schwarz here (actually, we can prove it this way) by noting that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{6}(a_i\pm b_i)^2\geq 0$ and expanding.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Since it is standard I'll spell out the solution:

By [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality):

$$(a_1b_1+\cdots+a_6b_6)^2 \le (a_1^2+\cdots+a_6^2)(b_1^2+\cdots+b_6^2) = 1$$

Finally take square root from both sides.

Comment: Is there any way to show this without cauchyschwartz because we didn't see it

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$|\mathbf{a}\circ \mathbf{b}|=||\mathbf{a}|\cdot|\mathbf{b}|\cos (\angle_{\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}})|\le |\mathbf{a}|\cdot|\mathbf{b}|$$

Comment: See what happened before editing the question

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3819853/revisions

Comment: Oh, sorry @Marek Krypsin. Also, +1